# Aggregate and update with mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to use the aggregate method to make my querys and modify my database by a value, I tried with $set but my database is not modified.

Here is how I do my query:

```
var filter = req.body.filter
var search = [ { $match: filter }, { $set: {item: "2"} }, { $sample: { size: 1 } }]
const result = await dataModel.aggregate(search)
```

I know there is also findOneAndUpdate but I would like to keep aggregate because I also want to use $project in my pipelines

thanks in advance !

Comment: You can try [Update with Aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/).

Comment: I have already searched but I can't find any pipeline that allows you to retrieve and modify a value at the same time

Comment: Transforming data (updating and removing) is the basic functionality one can achieve aggregation queries allow (in addition to other features). I am surprised.

Comment: I tried with $set and $rootReplace but neither of them allows to change the value in the BDD. The only way I have now is to do aggregate() then a findOneAndUpdate ...

Answer (score -1):

You can use FindOneAndUpdate for change your db

Comment: Please consider adding details to your answer. It is already mentioned in the body of the question that why the author wants to use ```aggregate``` in place of ```FindOneAndUpdate```.

Comment: Yes i want to use aggregate for get random document